# Sort List of List

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have List of Lists(list rows contain list column). I want to sort my rows in ListRZS by length(.size()).

```
[[123, 189, 277], [11], [145, 211, 299], [156, 222, 310], [167, 233, 255], [189, 266], [200, 277], [211, 288], [245, 299], [233], [244]]

Shoul be:
[[11], [233], [244], [189, 266],[200, 277], [211, 288], [245, 299], [123, 189, 277], [145, 211, 299], [156, 222, 310], [167, 233, 255]]
```

Question: How to write working comporator/comparable for this situation.

```
public class Start {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Start reading from Xls");
    ReaderXls1Column read = new ReaderXls1Column();
    ReaderXls readrzs = new ReaderXls();
    List<String> listASU = new ArrayList<String>(read.ReaderXls1Column("Text1obj",0,1));                        // Creating Lists
    List<List<String>>  listRZS = new ArrayList<List<String>>(readrzs.ReadXls("Text1obj",2,12));
    System.out.println(listASU);
    System.out.println(listRZS);
    System.out.println("Reading is over");
    System.out.println(listRZS);
    WriterXls.main("Text1obj",listRZS);
    System.out.println("Writing is over");
}
```

My attempt without comparator, comparable(of course, not working right)

```
        int k=0;
    while ( k<listRZS.size()){
        for (int j=0;j<10;j++)     {
            List<String> tmplist = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (listRZS.get(k).size()>listRZS.get(k+1).size()) {Collections.copy(listRZS.get(k),tmplist); listRZS.remove(k); listRZS.add(k+1,tmplist);}
            else {};
        }
        Collections.sort(listRZS.get(k));       // sort each row, solution above
        k++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) just needs to implement one method (`compare`), that takes two items, and returns:

- 0 if they are equal
- positive value if the second is less than the first
- negative value if the second is greater than the first.

When sorting integer values, a typical pattern to accomplish this is to reduce each object received in the `compare` method to an integer, then, if we call them `a` and `b`, simply return `a - b`.

**Example** (see it running at [ideone.com/rcmDbi](http://ideone.com/rcmDbi)):

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1);
        List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(1,2);
        List<Integer> c = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        List<Integer> d = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);

        List<List<Integer>> test = Arrays.asList(d,b,c,a);
        Collections.sort(test, ListSizeComparator.INSTANCE);
        for (List<Integer> list : test) {
            System.out.println(list.size());
        }
    }

    enum ListSizeComparator implements Comparator<List> {
        INSTANCE;

        public int compare(List one, List other) {
            return one.size() - other.size();
        }
    }
}
```

*(By the way, I've used an enum for the [enum singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399/143295) because our Comparator stores no state.)*

Comment: @Eldar This comparator will work for any type of list. In fact, you could change it to Collection and it would work for any Collection. Notice how it doesn't do anything with the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
List<List<String>>  myList; // load myList with values
```

Then do the sorting as follows:

```
 Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<List<String>>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(List<String> arg0, List<String> arg1) {

        return arg1.size() - arg0.size();
    }

    });
```

Comment: result: [189, 266, 277]
result is completely different;

Comment: what you mean by 'result is completely different'? whats the issue?